# Establishing shared memory between different processes with limited resources?

Tags: c++, c, process, shared-memory

After some painful debugging, I realized trying to use mmap to store a class in shared memory is horrendously stupid.

So, say that I have a class with something like 5 variables (strings and ints) that I would like to be accessible to all running processes. How could I go about coding this if I could not use non standard libraries like boost?

One idea that comes to mind, and it's pretty bad, is to make the variables global and then simply use mmap a few times. At first, I tried to do this but with the variables initially declared in the class and then mmap'd in the constructor, but from my understanding this does not work either.

I would like to add that I'm forced to use a version that does not support MAP_ANONYMOUS and only MAP_ANON.

Hold the phone. I, in this morning haze, have forgotten that I previously tested object mmap'ing and managed to update a member of the object from two different processes in a shared manner. I now believe my problem lies entirely in the construct initialization and the way that I declare the object. Yet a very similar access in my current code causes the process to abruptly end...

This is my code:

```
Hangman * H; // I've tried this with and without using new here
             // and this talk of placement new may show illumination
H =(Hangman*) mmap(NULL, sizeof *H, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

And here is the object:

```
struct Hangman{

        string word;
        string wCopy;
        int strikes, wLen;
        bool solved;
        int test;

        Hangman(){
                word = getWord();
                wLen  = word.length();
                wCopy = word;
                cout<<"wCopy in construc is: " <<wCopy<<endl;
                for(int i = 0; i < wLen; i++)
                        wCopy[i] = '_';
                strikes = 0;
                cout << wCopy <<endl;
                solved = false;
                test = 0;
        }  
 //(...)
 };
```

... and now the fact that I recall the int access to be fine and the string access to run amok leads me to believe I should not use string here. If this is the case, should I use a c style string?

Comment: Why is it horrendously stupid? If the class has a constructor, then you could use placement `new` (which is a form of `new` that lets you specify where the class is created) to construct it in the shared memory mapping. If it's a plain old `struct` with no constructor, then it's sufficient to just cast the address from `mmap()` to that type. Either way, you need to provide synchronization of course.

Comment: However, if the class manages memory you have to make sure chunks are allocated from the shared block and not somewhere else because otherwise they won't be available to other processes. And pointers get useless, as each process may map the shared block on different virtual addresses

Comment: @Diego: Yeah, that's a good point. This is probably a case where you ought to keep it simple. :)

Comment: Those `std::string` objects will be problematic as they might dynamically allocate memory. I'd stick to plain old data types (`char` arrays instead of `std::string`, etc.) for a shared memory segment. Could use a custom allocator too, but that's probably overcomplicating things to the extreme.

Comment: @Ulfalizer How exactly would you declare the char array? I'm having no luck with this technique.

Comment: @countofmontecristo: `char word[MAX_WORD_LEN]` for example. The crucial point is that memory allocated with plain `new` or `malloc()` in one of the processes won't be part of the shared memory mapping, and so can't be accessed by the other process. That also goes for classes that do this internally (e.g., `std::string` for longer strings). Unless it's just an exercise, you might want to ask yourself if you really need multiple processes too.

Comment: @Ulfalizer Then how would the mmap cast look? I've tried various casts and reinterpreted cast, and I can't compile without one.

Comment: @countofmontecristo: What you have at the moment looks fine. (Could use `static_cast` too, but it shouldn't make any difference.) Make sure to check for errors from `mmap()` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that C++ types are too clever to fit in shared memory, including `std::string`, not speaking of `unique_ptr` or containers.

Internally, a string will contain another pointer. And hell is just here : even if you put your string in shared memory, by default, it will point to the dynamic memory of one single process.

IMHO, this is one use case for remembering that all good old C types can be used from C++. And that fixed size char array and not always that bad, if you can accept the constraint of a maximum size for your words.

I would use :

```
struct Hangman{

    char word[MAXSIZE];
    char wCopy[MAXSIZE];
    int strikes, wLen;
    bool solved;
    int test;

    void init(string orig_word) {

        wLen = orig_word.length();
        if (wLen >= MAXSIZE) {
            // ERROR word is too long
        }
        strncpy(word, orig, wLen);
        word[wLen] = `\0`;
        for (int i=0; i<wLen; i++) wCopy[i] = '_';
        wCopy[wLen] = `\0`;

        cout<<"wCopy in init is: " << word <<endl;
        strikes = 0;
        cout << wCopy <<endl;
        solved = false;
        test = 0;
    }
}
```

That way, you can be sure that all elements used by the struct reside in shared memory. And you initialize the struct once allocated with its member function `init`.

Comment: This does solve the problem of the process from crashing, but I can't access wCopy later on in the program. cout << wCopy; and cout << wCopy[0]; both print blank lines even though I know that wCopy is initialized in init.

Comment: @countofmontecristo : assuming you did not forget the lines `for (int i=0; i<wLen; i++) wCopy[i] = '_'; wCopy[wLen] = `\0`;`, what is shown in init call for : `cout << wCopy <<endl;` 4 lines below ?

Comment: Yup, all that code is in there. The init call does exactly what's expected: "_______" I should add that the cout later on is H ->wCopy

Comment: @countofmontecristo : Hmm, wCopy is correctly initialized in `init`, but looses is value after some time. What happens between the moment it is initialized and the moment where you call  `cout << H->wCopy;` ? How do you write to `word` or `wCopy` ?

Comment: Here's a laugh. I called init... *starts cracking up insanely*  I... I c-called init....... BEFORE THE MMAP. OH MAN!! WHAT A CARD THAT BRAIN OF MINE! *enters Baltimore riots*